# Joomla custom xml options

Tags: xml, joomla, joomla2.5

Im playing with the joomla com_menus/models/forms/item.xml File.

I would like to use the feature of a SQL form field type as stated in joomla docs here.

http://docs.joomla.org/SQL_form_field_type

But i just cant seem to figure out how to get more than just one value.

My code is this:

```
<field 

    name="link" 
    type="sql" 
    default="" 
    class="articleselectbox" 
    label="Select an article" 

    query="

    SELECT #__content.id, #__content.alias, #__content.title, #__content.catid, #__categories.id, #__categories.alias 

    FROM 

    #__content 

    LEFT JOIN #__categories ON #__content.catid=#__categories.id 

    ORDER BY #__content.title" 

    key_field="alias" 

    value_field="catid" />
```

What i need is this as a final value:

```
#__categories.alias / #__content.id - #__content.alias . html
```

So the oputput would be:

```
poultry/12-organic-chicken-farming.html
```

I can get one value but the documentation dosent describe how to retrieve any more than that.

Anyone have any ideas on how this could be achieved please?

Cheers.
Jonny

Answer (score 0):

Sql field type creates a dropdown so you can only select one value you can concat the values from sql. As per my understanding this may help-

```
<field 
    name="link" 
    type="sql" 
    default="" 
    class="articleselectbox" 
    label="Select an article"
    query="SELECT 
    concat(#__categories.alias, '/', #__content.id,'-', #__content.alias,'.html') as value,              
    concat(#__categories.alias, '/', #__content.id,'-', #__content.alias,'.html') as title 
    FROM #__content 
    LEFT JOIN #__categories ON #__content.catid=#__categories.id 
    ORDER BY #__content.title" 
    key_field="title" 
    value_field="value" 
/>
```

Comment: @jonnypixel:if you need multiple selection set multiple="true" property.But this will need minor changes in model and controller also.

Answer (score 0):

```
    name="link"
    type="sql"
    multiple="false"
    size="1"
    label="Select an article "
    query="SELECT 
concat(#__categories.alias, '/', #__content.id,'-', #__content.alias,'.html') as value,              
concat(#__categories.alias, '/', #__content.id,'-', #__content.alias,'.html') as title 
FROM #__content 
LEFT JOIN #__categories ON #__content.catid=#__categories.id 
ORDER BY #__content.title"
    key_field="title"
    value_field="name"
    default="0"
    required="true"
    >
        <option value="">JOPTION_SELECT_LINK</option>
</field>
```

Now it will show all the